# How to prevent users from sharing my app without my permission

Tags: java, database, android-studio

I have created an offline android app that gets and stores data in an sqlite database. It does all sorts of calculations and displays the desired results and it works just fine. Now I want people to pay to be able to use the app. The problem is, they might share the app and everyone will use it without buying it from me. Is there anything I can do to avoid this?

Comment: If it's a fully offline app, then no, not really. If the app checks against a keyserver on first use, and creates a key file on the phone that is tied to the hardware ID, then yes it's quite doable to restrict sharing of the app. Obviously, if someone works out how the key file works, or if they decompile the app then there is little you can do to stop it, but it's really a non issue.

Comment: Thanks for the response. So how can I achieve that? What should I do to make the app create a key file on the phone?

Comment: There are thousands of ways to achieve this, right from doing it yourself with a plaintext file, to tying the app to a google account, or using an encrypted key that your app can decode/enccrypt and use. You'll need to do a bit of your own research to work out exactly how you want to do this, but if you get stuck on a specific part then feel free to ask a new question, and include your code and exact problem.

Comment: Thanks. I think tying the app to deviceID or imei will do. Will come again after some research with my code

Comment: @sorifiend thanks for your suggestions. I've managed to do it using firebase. Since I never wanted the users to logging using emails, I have created a database with user_IDs. The app will ask user to enter a user_ID on first use and checks if it is available in the database. If available, the app will store the deviceID in the database (so that no one can reuse the user_ID) as well as in sharedpreferences (which will check if the user is logged in or not) so that the user might continue using the app while offline. If the user logs out, the app will require internet again to login.